# Twisted inlineCallbacks benchmarking using another decorator

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using twisted and its decorator @inlineCallbacks

I'm trying to benchmark the execution time of a method that is decorated with @inlineCallbacks.

My question is - is it possible creating a new decorator for the calculation, or should I just add the calculation to the method itself:

```
@benchmark_performance
@inlineCallbacks
def perform():
    ...
```

vs

```
@inlineCallbacks
def perform():
    t1 = time.now()
    ...
    t2 = time.now()
    yield write_to_db(t2-t1)
```

Comment: "is it possible" questions are not very good.  Is that really what you want to know?  Sure, it's possible.  Did that help?

Answer (score 0):

That all depends.  The first example:

```
@benchmark_performance
@inlineCallbacks
def perform():
    ...
```

Would benchmark the performance of both the perform function as well as the inlineCallbacks decorator.

The second example will only bench marks the internals of the functionality of the perform function.

So if you want to include the performance for the inlineCallback (or any other decorator for that matter) then use the first method.  If you want to only benchmark the internals of the perform function then do it at a lower level.